# Filtering values of an array using pixel positions from an image

Tags: python, numpy

I have a image in greyscale. I have the value of each pixel saved to a text document that I pre-processed and loaded as an array, therefore my array has size 110529.

An example of how my array looks like:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.random.randint(low=18., high=36,size=(110592))
```

Then, I  used OpenCV to draw a ROI around the face in my image like this:

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.selectROI(my_frame)
```

and the values of x, y, w, h are:

```
 95 2 184 286
```

What I want to do is use the pixel indices in the ROI from that image as reference and use those indices to **extract to a new array** the values that are *inside* `my_array`, so I can have a filtered array with 52624 values that corresponds to the ROI in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you wanted is not called "filtering" but a ["numpy slice"](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy+slice):

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.selectROI(my_frame)
roi = my_frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```